# Make an image appear in front

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project with multiple players. I am trying to make name tags that appear right above the characters. (I can do that.) And I want the images to appear right in front of all of the objects, so you can see where they are through walls. I looked at the manual, and I saw the depth only function, but I don’t understand it. I am pretty stuck. Also, side question: do images have to be childed to the canvas to render, or what should I do with that. Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: Try out [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/878667/world-space-canvas-on-top-of-everything.html). And yes for UI to be rendered it must be childed to a canvas as Mattan Mohel commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you mean correctly, then I think the solution would be changing the canvas render mode to "Screen Space-Overlay", which should make it render on top. Additionally, for your other question: yes, UI components have to be childed to a canvas to be rendered

Comment: How would I make it always above the players, and if that would be too difficult, could I use sprites or something like that? Even if I use a gameObject, how would I make it visible?

Comment: Did you try using "Screen Space-Overlay" to see if it works?

Comment: Thank you it does.