# How can I display ui text above any gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to an empty GameObject.
The empty GameObject has a child Canvas and a ui text.  In the text there is some written text.

and I have a simple cube.
The ui text and the cube both dragged to the script in the inspector.

When I'm running the game I'm getting exception error in the editor :

MissingComponentException: There is no 'TextMesh' attached to the "Cube Text" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a TextMesh to the game object "Cube Text". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
AttachTextOnObjects.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/AttachTextOnObjects.cs:70)

[image: Hierarchy inspector settings]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AttachTextOnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEngine.GameObject[] objectsToAttachText;
    public UnityEngine.GameObject text;
    public float yPadding;
    public bool rotateNumbers = false;
    public float rotationSpeed = 10f;
    public bool textAbove = false;
    public bool textInFront = false;
    public bool textOnFaces = false;

    private List<GameObject> newTexts = new List<GameObject>();
    private MeshRenderer[] renderer;
    private Vector3 newPos;
    private GameObject newText;

    private void Start()
    {
        renderer = new MeshRenderer[objectsToAttachText.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToAttachText.Length; i++)
        {
            newText = Instantiate(text);
            renderer[i] = newText.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 objectsToAttachText[i].transform.position.x,
                 ((objectsToAttachText[i].transform.position.y + renderer[i].bounds.extents.y) + yPadding),
                   objectsToAttachText[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                newPos = new Vector3
                (
                 ((objectsToAttachText[i].transform.position.x + renderer[i].bounds.extents.x) + yPadding),
                 objectsToAttachText[i].transform.position.y,
                   objectsToAttachText[i].transform.position.z
                 );
            }

            newText.transform.position = newPos;
            //newText.transform.parent = objectsToAttachText[i].transform;
            var parent = objectsToAttachText[i].transform;//.parent.gameObject;
            GameObject go = new GameObject();
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 9.5f, 0);
            go.transform.Rotate(0, 77, -12);
            go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.3f, 0.1f, 1);
            go.name = "Object To Rotate Text";
            go.transform.parent = parent.transform;
            newText.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            newText.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
            newText.transform.parent = go.transform;

            newText.name = objectsToAttachText[i].name + " Text";
            newText.tag = "ObjectToAddText";
            newTexts.Add(newText);
            var textmesh = newText.GetComponent<TextMesh>();

            if (textAbove == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = i.ToString();
            }

            if (textInFront == true)
            {
                textmesh.text = objectsToAttachText[i].name;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (rotateNumbers == true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < newTexts.Count; i++)
            {
                newTexts[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 10 * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to position automatically a UI text above any gameobject.

Comment: Do you mean like health bar type UI? It wasn’t clear to me. Do you want the text to be above objects? That is what I understood.

Comment: @ken yes above the object/s and optional to make the object to be in front of the object/s so I have the textInFront flag.  but for now I want to put the text above the object/s.

Comment: Try adding text to the canvas as a child, and putting a script on the text that would set its transform to that of above a certain object each frame. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67186600/make-an-image-appear-in-front) might help.

Answer (score 1):

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'TextMesh' attached to the "Cube Text" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add a TextMesh to the game object "Cube Text". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it. AttachTextOnObjects.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/AttachTextOnObjects.cs:70)

This error means you're attempting to access a property on the gameobject "Cube Text" by the name of 'TextMesh', and that property doesn't exist.

There could be a couple tings causing this. Here's a quick list to help you debug it more effectively.

1. Make sure the instantiated prefab `public UnityEngine.GameObject text;` actually has a `TextMesh` component on it.
2. If the `TextMesh` component isn't on the cube, but is a child of the cube, use a different method to get the component. [Use `GetComponentsInChildren` instead](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) of `var textmesh = newText.GetComponent<TextMesh>();`
3. Make sure if `TextMesh` is really what you want, you may be using a plugin like TextMeshPro that has different component names than `TextMesh`. If you are, you need to use `TextMeshProUGUI` instead.
4. Consider checking to see if the component exists before attempting to access it's properties. You can do that with `if(textmesh is null)`.
5. Consider adding the component to the GameObject procedurally if it doesn't already exist. Such as: `var textmesh = newText.AddComponent<TextMesh>();`